# Entity Framework Core model in seprate plugin assembly

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework-core

I am working on a online shop module (class library) that is shared/reused among many web applications. I want this module to be in separate library.

What is the best practice of implementing common data model: products, orders etc. I would like to inject these entities into existing Db Context of these web applications.

Should I implement base db context or use some extensions methods, services or middleware?

Answer (score 1):

You can try by adding configuration classes for models implementing `IEntityTypeConfiguration` ie.

```
public abstract class DbEntityConfig<T> : IEntityTypeConfiguration<T> where T: class, IDbEntity
{
    public virtual void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<T> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(entity => entity.Id);
        builder.HasQueryFilter(entity => !entity.IsDeleted);
    }
}

 public class DummyEntityConfiguration: DbEntityConfig<Dummy>
     {
         public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Analysis> builder)
         {
            //Fluent Configuration here, especially table name
         }
     }
```

And then in DbContext OnModelCreating:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            builder.ApplyConfiguration(new DummyEntityConfiguration());
}
```

This adds models to DbContext. Then you could try applying configuration for each type deriving DbEntityConfig via reflection.

Access to models is possible via `DbContext.Set<T>`
Only cons of this solution is that without specifying ToTable in configuration, name of table will be exactly as model name (so no automatic pluralization) because EF core uses DbSet<> name as name of the table and if it's not available entity name.

Comment: OK, I understand. What about the database context class? I want to implement some business logic around these entities in the class library. For example I want to have Services that do CRUD operations.

Comment: Inject into service DbContext class and use DbContext.Set<T>. And in IoC container you can decide which class will you use as DbContext.

Comment: There is an issue that web application uses own db context. Of course web application db context could inherit from class library db context but what if I have couple class libraries with its own set of entities and db contexts?